# Return file not working when to download images from binary data in ASP.net MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to download a .png file but this code is not working for me. This action method is called by a button from partial View.

This is working only when I provide a .pdf file name but not working for images.

```
 public ActionResult Download(string DownloadsID)
      { 
                 var lst = (from a in doclst 

                       where a.Id == DataId

                       select new
                       {
                           a.DocName,
                           a.DocFile,

                       }).FirstOrDefault();

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyImage.png");
            return File(lst.DocFile, "image/png");
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] question to clarify what is happening and what you already done to debug so far.

Comment: i need to Download a png image stored in Sql server in var binary so i make an actionResult mentioned above this method runs without any error but i did'nt get any file on my view but when i changed file extension from png to pdf in   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyImage.pdf");    i get my data downloaded in pdf format

Comment: I am using Ajax to call my action method from view